# The page automatically scrolls/moves after selecting an option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, stimulusjs

I'm coding in `rails` and using Stimulus to connect views and javascript. For handling dropdowns, I'm using choices.js, which is an old library and not well supported atm. The issue that I currently have is, when I select an option from dropdowns, while `part of` dropdown is out of screen, the option is got selected and the page automatically scrolls down. It seems to me, when the half of the options goes off from the bottom of the screen and I'm selecting the top option the browser scrolls down to show/fit the whole dropdown for the next time! To be more clear, after scrolling if I click on dropdown again, the whole list is visible then. This automatic scrolling is not preferable for me. I tried to add scrolling back on `choice` event but it didn't work. I'm wondering if there is any css or javascript solution for it or not.

[before selecting the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1bv6.png)

[after selecting the option the screen scrolls down and when I click on dropdown the whole dropdown's options can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqXv2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to go with alpine.js

This way you can use all basic ( even somewhat advanced ) interactions without too much code.

In combination with Tailwind CSS2 you will have a good combo.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).